# disable selection in primefaces picklist

Tags: primefaces

Is there a way to disable the move buttons and drag n drop based on condition?
I want to disable the move\select from source to target(or vice versa) in case the target contains 3 item?

Is it possible? I couldn't find any answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `disabled` attribute of `picklist`, which disables the whole picklist.
You can pass call a backing bean attribute which returns a boolean value calculated according to your condition.

On your view

```
disabled="#{backingBean.targetHasThreeItems}"
```

and on backing bean

```
 public boolean targetHasTreeItems() {
    // here your code that calculates target item's count
   }
```